# Iterator JSF value

Tags: jsf, iterator, store

I want to know how to store a value from data iterator in a JSF page, so that I can use it in multiple place in a single iteration. Lets, say I want to display a particular value in 5 different places in a screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the problem you're struggling with. It sounds much like as if you're using JSF on JSP and are using *scriptlets* for that wherein you're repeating the `Iterator#next()` call multiple times within the loop body. This is indeed not going to work. Calling `next()` will obviously return the next item. You basically need to get hold of it in a variable only once in the loop and then reuse that variable multiple times. But anyway, using *scriptlets* in a JSF page is a huge smell.

When using JSP as view technology, the proper way would be using [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) [`<c:forEach>` tag](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html) or any JSF [`UIData`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIData.html) component, such as [`<h:dataTable>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/h/dataTable.html) or Tomahawk's [`<t:dataList>`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk20/tagdoc/t_dataList.html). All of them offers a `var` attribute wherein you can specify the scoped attribute name of the currently iterated item. You can use it as many times as you want in the tag body.

E.g.

```
<c:forEach items="#{bean.list}" var="item">
    #{item} ... #{item} ... #{item}
</c:forEach>
```

When you're using Facelets as view technology (which -fortunately- doesn't support *scriptlets*), you should be using the [`<ui:repeat>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/ui/repeat.html) tag for this.

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.list}" var="item">
    #{item} ... #{item} ... #{item}
</ui:repeat>
```

Answer (score 0):

[JSF 2.3](http://arjan-tijms.omnifaces.org/p/jsf-23.html) (JEE8) supports the [Iterable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) interface in UIData (DataTable) and UIRepeat ([Spec 1103](https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/issues/3789)) for the first time.